# Object is possibly 'undefined' should not throw error, since there is a rxjs filter above

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, eslint, lint

I'm currently refactoring a service of mine and came across a rather annoying issue.
I have an API which returns a object with multiple optional Properties. When I want to work with the Properties I first have to check weither this property is undefined or not, otherwise I will get an error. This can be done with an if-statement. After my refactoring i thought about putting the check inside the filter operator. This should work and only get me objects with the needed properties but now the linter still throws an error.

```
interface OptionalObject {
  values?: number[]
}

const obs$$ = new BehaviorSubject<OptionalObject>({});
obs$$.pipe(
  filter((val) => !!val.values),
  map((val) => val.values.length) // Object is possibly 'undefined'
).subscribe(() => {

});
```

I think my Project uses ESLint

I tried it with a if and it worked but I want it to work with the filter of Rxjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution is to use a TypeScript TypeGuard:

```
interface OptionalObject {
  values?: number[];
}

const obs$$ = new BehaviorSubject<OptionalObject>({});
obs$$
  .pipe(
    filter((val): val is {values: number[]} => !!val.values),
    map((val) => val.values.length)
  )
  .subscribe(() => {});
```

Comment: thanks i just thought of it myself but i'm not sure if it's a good solution, since every time you write a new type it's possible that you make a mistake and it wont be visible in the future. It's like adding a ! in front of values. It works but makes it hard to debug once you forget about it.

Comment: In this situation you need to challenge the situation making values undefined or the requirement to nest these values.

Comment: For this question and this situation, this answer is the solution to fix the linter error, since you now ensure that the values are indeed defined. If it answered the question you asked here, you should mark it as accepted :) whether it was architecturally correct to use this code in the first place, that's another question.